# Can a PyTorch DataLoader start with an empty dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a dataset which is in a `deque` buffer, and I want to load random batches from this with a `DataLoader`. The buffer starts empty. Data will be added to the buffer before the buffer is sampled from.

```
self.buffer = deque([], maxlen=capacity)
self.batch_size = batch_size
self.loader = DataLoader(self.buffer, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
```

However, this causes the following error:

```
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/loader/dataloader.py", line 78, in __init__
    super().__init__(dataset, batch_size, shuffle,
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 268, in __init__
    sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py", line 102, in __init__
    raise ValueError("num_samples should be a positive integer "
ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0
```

Turns out that the `RandomSampler` class checks that `num_samples` is positive when it is initialised, which causes the error.

```
if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples <= 0:
    raise ValueError("num_samples should be a positive integer "
                     "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))
```

Why does it check for this here, even though `RandomSampler` *does* support datasets which change in size at runtime?

One workaround is to use an `IterableDataset`, but I want to use the shuffle functionality of `DataLoader`.

Can you think of a nice way to use a `DataLoader` with a `deque`? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is neither the usage of *deque* nor the fact that the dataset is dynamically growable. The problem is that you are starting with a Dataset of size zero - which is invalid.

The easiest solution would be to just start with any arbitrary object in the deque and dynamically remove it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, this is the workaround I am using now, and it works fine for me. It does still feel quite unnatural to add a dummy object only to immediately remove it. Can you think of an engineering reason why starting a dataset with zero size should be invalid, even though it is valid for it to have a zero size during runtime? I might open a PyTorch issue about this.

Answer (score 0):

An empty dataset can be defined as follows:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

class EmptyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __len__(self):
        return 0

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        raise IndexError("Empty dataset cannot be indexed")
```

Creating/using a loader with `shuffle=False` is possible:

```
>>> loader = DataLoader(EmptyDataset(), batch_size=16, shuffle=False)
```

Iteration is also fine:

```
for batch in loader:
    print(batch)
```

---

#### What about `shuffle=True`?

However, when you specify `shuffle=True`, it breaks the `RandomSampler`:

```
>>> loader = DataLoader(EmptyDataset(), batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0
```

As a workaround, you can create your own sampler with the relevant error check adjusted from `self.num_samples <= 0` to `self.num_samples < 0`:

```
from torch.utils.data import RandomSampler

class MyRandomSampler(RandomSampler):
    r"""Samples elements randomly. If without replacement, then sample from a shuffled dataset.
    If with replacement, then user can specify :attr:`num_samples` to draw.

    Args:
        data_source (Dataset): dataset to sample from
        replacement (bool): samples are drawn on-demand with replacement if ``True``, default=``False``
        num_samples (int): number of samples to draw, default=`len(dataset)`.
        generator (Generator): Generator used in sampling.
    """
    data_source: Sized
    replacement: bool

    def __init__(self, data_source: Sized, replacement: bool = False,
                 num_samples: Optional[int] = None, generator=None) -> None:
        self.data_source = data_source
        self.replacement = replacement
        self._num_samples = num_samples
        self.generator = generator

        if not isinstance(self.replacement, bool):
            raise TypeError("replacement should be a boolean value, but got "
                            "replacement={}".format(self.replacement))

        if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples < 0:
            raise ValueError("num_samples should be a positive integer "
                             "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))
```

Then:

```
>>> loader = DataLoader(EmptyDataset(), batch_size=16, sampler=MyRandomSampler)  # shuffle=True)
```

Note that iterating this `loader` won't work, but I leave fixing that an exercise to the reader. (The fix is not obvious to me since the `Sampler` code is a bit intertwined.) One simple workaround is to override `DataLoader.__iter__` or `._get_iterator`.